# Tensorflow classification predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification

I'm dealing with a simple classification problem and I'm new to it. I want it to give results like 0 and 1, but it gives a percentage ending as below. how can i solve this? There are 2 targets in the label column in the data set.

```
input_dict = {name: tf.convert_to_tensor([value]) for name, value in sample.items()}
predictions = model.predict(input_dict)
prob= tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions[0])
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are the two targets `0, 1`? If yes you could do `pred=np.round(prob)`.

Comment: actually the names of the 2 tags, 'long' and 'short'. I want to get a result like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also  set a threshold for model prediction like 50/60/70 % , if threshold > 50/60/70% , label it as long as it is short.

```
input_dict = {name: tf.convert_to_tensor([value]) for name, value in sample.items()}
predictions = model.predict(input_dict)//Normal returns a confidence score.
prob= tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions[0])
if prob > 0.6 : //(Threshold is 60% here you can change according to your requirement)
  print("long")
else:
  print("short")
```